# How to restore previous window splits in emacs

Tags: emacs, split

This is an annoying issue for a long time, at least to me.

Suppose I have split the windows in certain ways. Then I found that it is difficult to view a file in a small windows, then I do C-x 1 to get a better view. But is there any way I can restore my previous window splits?

For example, when using gdb-many-windows (5 windows by default), the source code is shown in middle. I would like to view in big window (single window) then restore my original split setting (5 windows).

Hope I explain things clear.

Thanks

Comment: As per the duplicate, use `(winner-mode 1)` and then simply `C-c <left>` (repeatedly if necessary) whenever you want to undo changes to a frame's window configuration. `C-c <right>` returns you to the most-recent arrangement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to do it programatically in elisp is to use the `current-frame-configuration` function to get a list, which you can then use to restore it later.

Thus:

```
(setq my-window-list (current-frame-configuration))
```

and later:

```
(set-frame-configuration my-window-list)
```

You can easily wrap those in a function to save and load and then bind them to a key binding (possibly overriding c-x 1 so you always save on singe-window-expand).

Answer (score 4):

I often use registers to save/restore window configurations. For instance, to save it in register `a` do

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>

Then, to restore

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>

See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WindowsAndRegisters for more detail.

There are also many other, fancier tools to work with window configurations, like [e2wm](https://github.com/myuhe/emacs-window-manager) which is especially useful if you like to use several pre-set window configurations. See also http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryWindows#toc4 for some other tools.